# is there any possibility to access ConfigurationAPI inside UserAuthenticationSecurityCheck extended Class

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

adapter UserAuthenticationSecurityCheck where we have introduced some properties in the adapter.xml file outside the securityCheckDefinition. Which i am able to configure in the Adapter -> Configuration tab in the mfp console.

We are trying to access the configuartion value via ConfigurationAPI with importing 
import com.ibm.mfp.adapter.api.ConfigurationAPI inside the UserAuthenticationSecurityCheck extended class.

But we are getting a null pointer exception during this process. I am able to access them inside the java-adapter class via ConfigurationAPI but not inside the security UserAuthenticationSecurityCheck class.

Wanted to access the below image properties inside the UserAuthenticationSecurityCheck extended class.

[image]

```
public class userSecurityCheck extends UserAuthenticationSecurityCheck {

    @Context
    ConfigurationAPI configurationAPI;


    @Override
    protected boolean validateCredentials(Map<String, Object> credentials){

        String instancename = credentials.get("instancename").toString();
        // java null pointer exception is happening at the below line
        String httpUrl = configurationAPI.getPropertyValue(instancename);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds to me like what you're really looking for is an extension point to extend the configurable elements in UserAuthenticationSecurityCheck.  Is that a fair characterization?  I don't know if MFP supports subclassing those objects or not.  I'll try to find out for you though.

Comment: @JohnGerken Please view the updated question

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a way to specify configurable properties on the "Security Check" flavour of adapter, and it is different from the regular type of adapter. It is documented [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/creating-a-security-check/#security-check-configuration). I have validated that this approach works. The documentation omits a few key elements, like package names, so below is so very simple example code to demonstrate:

`UserAuth.java`:

```
public class UserAuth extends UserAuthenticationSecurityCheck {
  @Override
  protected boolean validateCredentials(Map<String, Object> credentials) {
    String test_property = ((UserAuthSecurityCheckConfig) this.config).test_property;
    LOG.warning("auth test_property=" + test_property);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public SecurityCheckConfiguration createConfiguration(Properties properties) {
      return new UserAuthSecurityCheckConfig(properties);
  }
}
```

`UserAuthSecurityCheckConfig.java`:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import com.ibm.mfp.security.checks.base.UserAuthenticationSecurityCheckConfig;

public class UserAuthSecurityCheckConfig extends UserAuthenticationSecurityCheckConfig {
    public String test_property;

    public UserAuthSecurityCheckConfig(Properties properties) {
        super(properties);
        this.test_property = this.getStringProperty("test_property", properties, "defaultValueInCode");
    }
}
```

`adapter.xml`:

```
<securityCheckDefinition name="UserLogin" class="com.xyz.UserAuth">
    <property name="test_property" displayName="Test Property Auth" defaultValue="foo_default_in_xml"  />
</securityCheckDefinition>
```